# Is it possible to overload the set() function?

Tags: python, function, set, overloading

I know that most python built-in functions cannot be overloaded, and some like `int()`, `float()`, and `bool()` can; is it possible with `set()`?. There is already an unrelated `__set__` method used for setting properties, but if int() can be overloaded, can set()?

Comment: Do you mean that you want a special method to be called on an object `x` when `set(x)` is executed?

Comment: No, it can't. And `set` has nothing to do with `__set__`

Comment: `set = lambda x: x+1`. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: @khelwood exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no [magic `__method__`](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/)  that lets you override `set()`.